# Pandas groupby and then pivot is not returning the desired output

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
CA          Amount    Payment_Mode    Trans    
1001        230       Non-Digi        Normal
1001        330       Website         Normal
1001         40       Website         PPI
1002        100       Card            PPI
1002        700       Website         PPI
1002        100       Card            Normal
```

Now I want a resultant dataframe `df_f` as follows where `Payment_Mode` count and `Trans` count are captured in column wise:

```
CA          Amount     Non-Digi     Website     Card     Normal    PPI
1001        600          1             2          0        2        1
1002        900          0             1          2        1        2
```

My Approach:

```
df_1 = df.groupby(['CA']).agg(Amount = ('Amount','sum'),
                          Payment_Mode = ('Payment_Mode','count'),
                          Trans = ('Trans','count')).reset_index()
df_f = df_1.pivot(index='CA', columns = 'Payment_Mode', values = '???') <-- This is where I am stuck
```

Any clue on this?

Comment: didnt test it, but have u tried pivot_table and probably use count for ur aggfunc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) first and then add aggregated sum colum:

```
df_1 = (df.groupby('CA').sum()
          .join(df.melt(id_vars='CA',value_vars=['Payment_Mode','Trans'])
                  .pivot_table(index='CA', columns='value', values = 'variable',aggfunc='count', fill_value=0))
          .reset_index())
print (df_1)
     CA  Amount  Card  Non-Digi  Normal  PPI  Website
0  1001     600     0         1       2    1        2
1  1002     900     2         0       1    2        1
```

Comment: I am getting an error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'`. I am unsing pandas 0.25

Comment: @pythondumb - hmm, so `df.groupby('CA')['Amount'].sum()` is chaned some way? If yes, be free remove `to_frame()`

Comment: I alraedy did that but I am getting an error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`. My actual dataset has some more columns which are to be melt. So, in general, why I am getting this error?

Comment: @pythondumb - how looks melt in your code? I think how you change `df.melt(id_vars='CA',value_vars=['Payment_Mode','Trans'])`

Comment: Ok so I changed few things in your code. 1. `aggfunc = 'size'` to `count`.  and then 2. removed `to_frame()`. My `df_melt` actually creates a stacked `df` where `value` is not a number rather strings.

Comment: @pythondumb - data are confidental?

Comment: hey can you please come to chat? Yes Data is confidential but I can do something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206414/discussion-between-jezrael-and-pythondumb).